# SQL инъекция, сработает ли она на этом коде?

Tags: php, mysql

Страница авторизации. Смогут сделать sql инъекцию?

```
<?php 
    include("sql.php"); 
    session_start(); 
    function Fix($str) { 
        $str = trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { 
            $str = stripslashes($str); 
    } 
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str); 
    } 
    $errmsg = array(); 
    $errflag = false; 
    $username = Fix($_POST['username']);
    $password = Fix($_POST['password']);
    if($username == '') { 
        $errmsg[] = 'Username missing'; 
        $errflag = true; 
    } 
if($password == '') { 
    $errmsg[] = 'Password missing'; 
    $errflag = true; 
    }
if($errflag) { 
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG'] = $errmsg; 
    session_write_close(); 
    header("location: login.php"); 
    exit(); 
} 
$qry = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Username` = '$username' AND `Password` = '" . md5($password) . "'"; 
$result = mysql_query($qry); 
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) { 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $_SESSION['UID'] = $row['UID'];
        $_SESSION['USERNAME'] = $username;
        session_write_close(); 
        header("location: member.php");
    } 
} else { 
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG'] = "Invalid username or password"; 
    session_write_close(); 
    header("location: login.php"); 
    exit(); 
    } 
?>
```

А вот код страницы регистрации. Смогут ли сделать sql инъекцию и получить базу или внести в нее изменения?

```
<?php 
        include("sql.php"); 
        session_start(); 
        function Fix($str) { 
            $str = @trim($str); 
            if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { 
                $str = stripslashes($str); 
        } 
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str); 
        } 

        $errmsg = array(); 

        $errflag = false; 

        $UID = "12323543534523453451465685454";
        $username = Fix($_POST['username']);
        $email = $_POST['email']; 
        $password = Fix($_POST['password']);
        $rpassword = Fix($_POST['rpassword']);

        if(!eregi("^([0-9]{9})$", $username)) { 
            $errmsg[] = 'Username missing'; 
            $errflag = true; 
        } 


     if(!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)) { 
        $errmsg[] = 'Invalid Email'; 
        $errflag = true; 
     } 

     if($password == '') { 
        $errmsg[] = 'Password missing'; 
        $errflag = true; 
    } 

    if($rpassword == '') { 
        $errmsg[] = 'Repeated password missing';
        $errflag = true; 
    } 

    if(strcmp($password, $rpassword) != 0 ) { 
        $errmsg[] = 'Passwords do not match';
        $errflag = true; 
    } 

    if($username != '') { 
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Username` = '$username'"; 
        $result = mysql_query($qry); 
        if($result) { 
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                $errmsg[] = 'Username already in use'; 
                $errflag = true; 
            } 
            mysql_free_result($result); 
        } 
    } 

    if($errflag) { 
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG'] = $errmsg; 
        session_write_close(); 
        header("location: register.php");
        exit(); 
    } 

    $qry = "INSERT INTO `users`(`UID`, `Username`, `Email`, `Password`) VALUES('$UID','$username','$email','" . md5($password) . "')"; 
    $result = mysql_query($qry); 


    if($result) { 
        echo "Благодарим Вас за регистрацию, " .$username . ". Пожалуйста, входите <a href=\"login.php\">сюда</a>"; 
        exit(); 
    } else { 
        die("Ошибка, обратитесь позже"); 
        } 

    ?>
```

Comment: Я инъекций тоже не увидел, но соглашусь с ответом, код ужасен и вроде как даже некоторые проверки неправильные

Comment: мне просто интересно, а если зарегистрироваться с ником `<script>alert(1);</script>nick` и посмотреть профиль этого пользователя другим пользователем - что он увидит? )

Answer (score 4):

Нет, конкретно в этом коде инъекции не будет.

Несмотря на это, данный подход не защитит от инъекции во множестве других случаев.

Кроме того, сам по себе этот код просто ужасен. Начиная с использования отсутствующих в языке модулей mysql и eregi, и заканчивая тем, что в нем намешана куча никак не связанных между собой  и часто бессмысленных проверок.